# Custom submit handler never gets called

Tags: 8, forms

I want to check a data when an user submits a form. I set a custom submit handler in form alter, but my custom handler function never gets called. I don't understand why.

This is my code :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custommodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == "node_test_form") {
        kint("toto"); //toto is displayed when I load the form page
        $form_state->setSubmitHandlers(array("_custommodule_test"));
    }
}

function _custommodule_test(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
    kint("mwahahaa?"); // never displayed
    die(); // doesn't work, the submit form page loaded successfully
}
```

I cleared cache, but the issue is still there.

### Edit ##

I tested add a validate handler, the problem persists.. The code :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custommodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == "node_test_form") {
        kint("toto"); //toto is displayed when I load the form page
        $form_state->setSubmitHandlers(array("custommodule_myform_mysubmit"));
        $form_state->setValidateHandlers(array("custommodule_myform_myvalidate"));
        $form_state->getSubmitHandlers(); // display array("custommodule_myform_mysubmit")
        $form_state->getValidateHandlers(); // display array("custommodule_myform_myvalidate")
    }
}

function custommodule_myform_mysubmit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
    kint("submit ?"); // never displayed
    die(); // doesn't work, the submit form page loaded successfully
}

function ccustommodule_myform_myvalidate(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
    kint("Validate ?"); // never displayed
    die(); // doesn't work, the submit form page loaded successfully
}
```

Comment: Don't prefix the function name with _

Comment: I guess you have to name it right.

custommodule_form_submit 

that should do it.

Or you can go and write a constraint plugin for it 

https://www.drupalwatchdog.com/volume-5/issue-2/introducing-drupal-8s-entity-validation-api

Comment: I tested with "custommodule_toto_submit" and cleared caches, but the issue is still there

Comment: Creating my own constraint plugins seems be a solution.. but my way must be work and I would klike understand why a stupid handler adding doesn't work =)

Comment: [edit] converting to answer...

Answer (score 1):

validate and submit handlers are added to the corresponding form element, e.g. `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'foo'`.  and same for #validate.

Honestly no idea what those methods are used for, never used them. Maybe internally, during form processing.

Also note that the node form currently has multiple submit buttons (save as published, unpublished and so on), so you'd probably need to add your submit to all of those.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8.2 you can used below code inside file mymodule.module

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

   if($form_id == "node_video_form") {  
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
        if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
            $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_video_form_submit';
        }
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_video_form_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('It works!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this foreach function to add the custom submit form to all submit buttons:

```
  // Set a custom submit function
  foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
    if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
      $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_custom_submit';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

kint("submit ?"); // never displayed die(); // doesn't work, the submit form page loaded successfully

If you use "die();" in submit or validate handle, then it will stop script, but will not print any data of form object or any other things which you want to print because it is not a custom form , it is a node form so simply you can use "\Drupal::logger" to store that values in recent log and then verify your required results to visit recen log message area in your Drupal site.

$data = "Any value you want to print here". Use this : \Drupal::logger('YOUR_module_name')->info($data1);